# Show that sum over $1/k+(-1)^k/\sqrt{k}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help with the following problem:

a) Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$ diverges.

b) Show that $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k-\sqrt{k}}$$ converges.

For b) I have that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k-\sqrt{k}}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}}_{\to1}=0$$ so the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}a_{k}$ converges by the Leibniz criterion.

But I don't know how to handle a). The alternating part gives me trouble to find a divergent minorant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}$ is convergent, if it were the case that $\displaystyle\sum\left(\dfrac{1}{k}+\dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$ being convergent, then so does the case that $\displaystyle\sum\left(\dfrac{1}{k}+\dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}-\dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{k}}\right)=\sum\dfrac{1}{k}$, which is a contradiction.

For the second question, you need also to justify that $\dfrac{1}{k-\sqrt{k}}$ is eventually decreasing.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds reasonable. I will now think about the "decreasing" part.